# CSS Z-Index layering issue

Tags: html, css, z-index

I got a nice idea for a webpage layout and started to design then code it. And when i was done with the menu, i thought YIHA! But after a few moments i noticed that the .menu-item that is going to the top of the page is going behind my .logo class even if it has a higher z-index.

**Here is a sass cutout:**

```
    li.menu-item
      list-style: none
      position: absolute
      z-index: 200

      &:hover > a
        background-color: #a82929
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
        margin-right: 0px

      a
        text-decoration: none
        color: #ffffff
        box-sizing: border-box
        padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px
        margin-right: 22px
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out
        position: relative
        z-index: 300
```

[Link to the CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjWWLQ)

Tried to watch some videos about z-index, amongst them one from css-tricks, but i still don't get it to work as i want. Help me stackoverflooooow, your my only hope...

Comment: Please include a reproducible example in the question. That would include the HTML also, and the compiled CSS I guess. But anyway, take a look at this: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: how do you mean reproducible example. i only include a piece of code because otherwise i could not link to codepen. didn't really get why i have to include code here to link to codepen, the code is there? and most of the time for people to understand the problem they have to se the whole sass code otherwise you dont get the context. should i include the whole 200+ lines of sass in my question to? plus the jade and js?

Comment: What happens is Codepen goes down? Then this question and its answers may not be any help to anyone. Stack Overflow is not willing to rely on outside parties, so a complete _but minimal_ example should always be in the question itself. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for letting me know. i thought that they wanted to keep the post small, but then i will include as much code as needed here next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess your problem is this:

`.menu-box` has a `z-index` of 20.

`.logo-box` has a `z-index` of 40.

And both have `position: relative;` Therefore, everything inside those two will get "layered" only inside the two, individually. Nothing in the `.menu-box` will go above `.logo-box` because of those `z-index`'s that I mentioned above. Everything inside those will be "layered" only inside these two parent boxes, the `z-index`'s of the inside elements will also only matter inside the parent elements.

I will also just leave this here: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: so what you are saying is that the way it is coded now the menu-items cant go over the logo? But you write that they both have position relative but menu-box has a position of absolute and logo-box has relative, they do have different parents so i have to rewrite the code a bit to make it work then? bummer. thank you for the link, will look at it.

Comment: @Robban Right, both of them don't have `position: relative;`, sorry for that. But anyway, what I said should still mostly apply, so take a moment to understand how `z-index` works, the link should help you quite a lot with that. Especially, pay attention to the fact that `z-index` is not universal for the whole document, and you will need to figure out how the positions that you set affect the scope of it.

Comment: Yes you are so right my dear friend. Just wanted to know if it made any difference if one of them where relative. But i thank you so much beacuse your answer made me solve the problem. i had to move the 'nav' in the same parent as the rest and then it worked. I appreciate you took time to write such a good answer to my question, made me think a little not just gave me the answer,that is needed sometimes to but not this time. if it is as you say you could use the same z-index in different parents because it only applies in that parent?